# Error in setting the query string parameter

Tags: visualforce

This is a vf page, trying to get &set the  query string parameter
The page compiled successfully and showing the list of related contacts but when I click the contact name link the following error occurs

> **Insufficient Privileges** 
>   You do not have the level of access necessary
>   to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of
>   the record or your administrator if access is necessary. For more
>   information, seeInsufficient Privileges Errors.

```
<apex:page standardController="account">
  <apex:form >
   <apex:pageBlock title="contacts" >
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!account.contacts}" var="ca">
     <apex:column headerValue="Name" >
      <apex:commandLink > {! ca.name}
       <apex:param name="cid" value="{ca.id}"/>
       </apex:commandLink>
       </apex:column>
      <apex:column value="{!ca.email}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
   </apex:pageBlock>
   <apex:detail subject="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.cid}" relatedList="false"/>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Anybody have solution for this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please provide code for link which redirects to other page.

Answer (score 1):

Try following changes in the tag as below:

Change

```
<apex:commandLink > {! ca.name}
   <apex:param name="cid" value="{ca.id}"/>
</apex:commandLink>
```

to

```
<apex:commandLink action="/{!$CurrentPage.URL}?cid={!ca.id}"> 
 {! ca.name}
</apex:commandLink>
```